# CSV node import using feeds module on a Mac

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

I'm using the feeds module to try to import several thousand nodes, but I'm getting mixed results: sometimes it seems to work, sometimes it doesn't.
I understand there are some sort of issues related with the line endings in the CSV files when they are created on a Mac. I tried saving my CSV for Unix (LF) and Windows (CRLF), but that doesn't seem to fix the problem entirely either.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is there a definitive solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the most success importing CSV files by importing them into Google Docs (spreadsheet) first and then exporting from Google Docs as a CSV file. It might seem like a silly workaround but Google spreadsheets seems to handle inconsistencies in CSV files a little better than Excel or Numbers.

Give it a shot. I've just used the same method for a Feeds CSV import.